# cPanel shared host: Unable to initialize module

Tags: php, laravel, hosting, cpanel, shared-hosting

I have recently transferred a Laravel application over to my clients web server. The application works fine locally and on my private server.

When trying to load the application on the clients server I get a http 500 error as Laravel requires PHP >= v7.1.3. Normally in cPanel you can change the PHP version by going to "software > select php version". As this option wasn't their I changed the PHP version through the `.htaccess` file by adding this line:

```sh
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php73 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

This successfully changed PHP `v5.4.45` to `v7.3.1`.

However when I now try to load the application I get the following error:

> Class 'PDO' not found

On the server the error log returns the following:

> [17-Nov-2019 12:15:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo.so: undefined symbol: _zval_ptr_dtor), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo.so.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
>   [17-Nov-2019 12:15:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_sqlite: Unable to initialize module
>   Module compiled with module API=20100525
>   PHP    compiled with module API=20180731
>   These options need to match
>    in Unknown on line 0
>   [17-Nov-2019 12:15:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_mysql: Unable to initialize module
>   Module compiled with module API=20100525
>   PHP    compiled with module API=20180731
>   These options need to match
>    in Unknown on line 0

As this is a shared host I do not have access to the `/usr/ directory` so I can not change any configuration files.

At this point I think my only option is for the hosting company to fix this directly.

Is there anything that I could do myself to get this working? 
I am now out of ideas.

Comment: I think you are right you have to contact the hosting company.

Answer (score 1):

Pear packages or php extension option are able in your cpanel you would find the package or extension you need.otherwise talk to the hosting providers.

Comment: Do you know which pear packages i would need to install? I see this option but I don't see any specific packages for pdo_sqlite or pdo_mysql

Comment: if you don't find the extension please contact hosting providers.because on shared hosting usually there are many restriction.